# Display only those records which do not have a certain key qualifier

Tags: sql, database

So I have a table which has a composite primary key for SHIP# & REF#. Each SHIP# has multiple codes for REF# which are BM, PO, CS, RT etc. CS field is mandatory but the others only get populated when the user actually inputs something. So, a basic select would display something like this:

```
SHIP#           REF#    VALUE
000002          CS      20001836                      
000002          PO      020  
000002          BM      MIDLANDAV         
000003          CS      20001834                      
000003          PO      8-694
000004          CS      200POLDQ                         
000004          BM      20001835
000005          CS      SEN6790C
```

Now, you will notice that shipment 000004 has only CS & BM and no PO.

I want to display all shipments with CS's values. So, if the PO value is empty or doesn't exist like in case '000004' & '000005', only those records should show. Since the CS is mandatory we'll have to get all records where CS exists but there shouldn't be PO field.

So, the output should be:

```
SHIP#           REF#    VALUE                     
000004          CS      200POLDQ                         
000005          CS      SEN6790C
```

Let me know if you need more clarifications. Thanks.

Comment: . . I removed the inconsistent database tags.  Tag only with the database you are really using.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `not exists`:

```
select t.*
from t
where t.ref# = 'CS' and
      not exists (select 1
                  from t t2
                  where t2.ship# = t.ship# and t2.ref# = 'PO'
                 );
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the answers but this seems to work as well.

```
select a.ship#
from a
left join b on b.ship# = a.ship# and b.ref# = 'PO'
where a.ref# = 'CS' and b.ship# is null;
```